# deontic sense with the third person

Tags: vocabulary, modal-verbs

> All boys **will** attend roll-call at 8 o’clock.

Above sentence is from a [Korean](http://www.kyobobook.co.kr/product/detailViewKor.laf?ejkGb=KOR&mallGb=KOR&barcode=9788938704849&orderClick=LAG&Kc=) dictionary, which says it can denote *order or instruction*. It’s not common to use the meaning when the subject is the third person, it says. Then if the subject is replaced by ‘*she*,’ can’t this sentence take the sense of order or instruction at all: ‘*she will attend roll-call at 8 o’clock*’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you say:

> All boys attend roll-call at 8 o’clock.

you are stating a scheduled occurrence, that's all.

But when you say:

> All boys **will** attend roll-call at 8 o’clock.

it seems that there was some order, expectation or requirement that this will happen. If spoken, the word *will* might be emphasized.

Same would apply to:

> She attends roll-call at 8 o’clock.

and

> She will attend roll-call at 8 o’clock.